# EvtOpenChannelEnum access denied

Tags: windows, winapi, event-log

I'm calling `EvtOpenChannelEnum` after having gotten a valid session handle with `EvtOpenSession`.  `EvtOpenSession` worked, but `EvtOpenChannelEnum` is returning access denied (`GetLastError = 5`).

Why would this be?  If there was an access problem, I'd expect to hit it with the `EvtOpenSession` call.  What's more perplexing, the user can get on the same computer with my program, logged in as the same user, and use the *Windows Event Log Viewer* (2008, so assuming it's using the same API) and it works fine.

Stumped...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have the required permission on the remote server.  This is not checked immediately, but when you use the handle for the first time.

From the docs for [EvtOpenSession](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385462%28v=VS.85%29.aspx):

> This function does not validate the
>   credentials; the credentials are
>   validated the first time you try to
>   use the session handle. If the
>   credentials are not valid, the call
>   will fail with ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.